# Understanding xreadgroup command

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer

I have written `redis stream consumer` in python and the `minimal code` looks as below:

```
key = 'order_completed'
group = 'inventory_group'

redis.xgroup_create(key, group)  #statement1

result = redis.xreadgroup(group, key, {key: '>'}, None) #statement2
```

**I need help to understand the last two statements.**

My limited understanding is that `redis.xgroup_create(key, group)` is creating a `consumer group.`

And, `redis.xreadgroup(group, key, {key: '>'}, None)` is used to read latest entry in the stream.

What is `{key: '>'}`?

I have already read [xreadgroup](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup/) but not able to understand much from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` special stream entry ID makes XREADGROUP to return only the stream entries which were never delivered to any consumer in the group - basically, it will return **new entries only**.

Apart from `>`, the command accepts any other regular stream entry ID: in that case, XREADGROUP returns the stream entries **already delivered to the calling consumer**, whose IDs are greater than the passed value.

From the [command documentation](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup/):

> The ID to specify in the STREAMS option when using XREADGROUP can be
> one of the following two:
>
> - The special > ID, which means that the consumer want to receive only
>   messages that were never delivered to any other consumer. It just
>   means, give me new messages.
> - Any other ID, that is, 0 or any other
>   valid ID or incomplete ID (just the millisecond time part), will have
>   the effect of returning entries that are pending for the consumer
>   sending the command with IDs greater than the one provided. So
>   basically if the ID is not >, then the command will just let the
>   client access its pending entries: messages delivered to it, but not
>   yet acknowledged. Note that in this case, both BLOCK and NOACK are
>   ignored.